# Perl program doesn't print the output.. 

Tags: perl

What changes is to be made to the program so as to print the output in other text file, reading from first text file.
Currently it is not giving the output in other text file, reading from first text file.

I think program is correct upto some extent but still needs to be go through Review...

```
Program is as follows :
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #     This program is intended for storing the sentences in a text file with following conditions: #
    #   1. The first letter of a sentence in upper case.                       #
    #   2. As sentence completes at [. or ? or !], the succeeding character i.e. beginning     #
    #      character of other sentence in upper case.                          #
    #   3. There may be combinations of more than one [. or ? or !] "WITH Spaces".         #
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use strict;

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #     "File::Slurp" used for reading whole file by use of a scalar variable        #
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    use File::Slurp;

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #     "File::Slurp qw( :all)" used for getting all subs in the module exported     #
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    use File::Slurp qw( :all );

    #======== BLOCK-1 ==========#
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #                 Opens File if exists else file could not open                    #
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    open (FILE, 'matter.txt') || die("Could not open file!");

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #   "File::Slurp" used : by "read_file" AND "write_file" functions,        #
    #           using scalar variable                      #
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    my $LowText_1 = read_file( 'matter.txt' );  #==== (R1_orig)

    my $UpText;
    my $ch;

    my $i=0;

    while($i < eof(FILE))       ## BLOCK-1 + BLOCK-2 (START)
    {
    #======== BLOCK-1 ==========#
     while($i < eof(FILE))
     {
        if($ch eq " ")
        {
        $ch = uc($ch);
        my $UpText = write_file('UpFirst_matter.txt', $ch); #==== (2)
        print "$UpText\n";
        my $LowText_2 = read_file( 'matter.txt' );  #==== (R2)
        }
        else
        {
        my $UpText = write_file('UpFirst_matter.txt', $ch);
        my $LowText_1 = read_file( 'matter.txt' );  #==== (R1)
        }
     }$i++;     #==== (4)

     close(FILE) || die("Could not close file!!");

    #======== BLOCK-2 ==========#
     #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
     #                 Opens File if exists else file could not open                    #
     #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
     open (FILE, 'matter.txt') || die("Could not open file!");

     #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
     #  "File::Slurp" used : by "read_file" AND "write_file" functions,         #
     #          using scalar variable                       #
     #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
     my $LowText_2 = read_file( 'matter.txt' ); #==== (R2_orig)

    #======== BLOCK-2 ==========#
     while($i < eof(FILE))
     {
        if($ch eq "." || $ch eq "?" || $ch eq "!")
        {
        my $ch = uc($ch);
        my $UpText = write_file('UpFirst_matter.txt', $ch); #==== (3(x))
        print "$UpText";
        my $LowText_1 = read_file( 'matter.txt' );  #==== (R1)
        }
        else
        {
        my $UpText = write_file('UpFirst_matter.txt', $ch);
        my $LowText_2 = read_file( 'matter.txt' );  #==== (R2)
        }
     }$i++;     #==== (4)

    close(FILE) || die("Could not close file!!");   #==== (4_end)
    }$i++;              ## BLOCK-1 + BLOCK-2 (END)
```

Comment: can anybody help me in the code. Seeking for help..

Comment: I'd suggest you either step your code through the debugger or sprinkle `warn` instructions around to get a trace of what's going on.

Comment: Actually i am debugging it manually, but the only thing is i am not able to know where the problem is in the code?

Comment: I just want to perform operation which is mentioned in the program but it is not printing any output.

Comment: So many strange things in this code. Can I suggest that you start by reading something like "Learning Perl"? Some things that make no sense at all: "while ($i < eof((FILE))", using $ch without assigning a value to it, incrementing $i *outside* the loop.

Comment: Please state all requirements! Amit: Why do you need to read character by character? From the code snippet you gave, I can conclude that normal line-by-line reads are ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $content = read_file('x.txt');
$content =~ s/([.!?]\s*|^)(\pL)/$1\U$2/g;
write_file('y.txt', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

- use'ing `File::Slurp` twice is redundant. Remove the one that's most unspecific ( the first one)
- 2 argument form of `open` is deprecated for a long time already. Use 3-arg form:

  my $file;
   open ($file, '<', 'matter.txt') or die;
- From the documentation of [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm) you don't even need to open() the file:

  # read in a whole file into an array of lines `my @lines = read_file('filename');`
- Perl's own documentation of [open()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) has lots of examples and you can copy a typical file readin loop from there
- If you do use file slurp as written in the documentation you can write out "the whole file" at once(!) with

  # write out a whole file from an array of lines write_file( 'filename', @lines ) ;
- So you need to

  1. use File::Slurp to `read_file()` the whole file, then iterate over the array to modify the content, then `write_file()` the whole array at once, or
  2. do not use File::Slurp and just open the two files (one with '<' for reading, one with '>' for writing)
- `File::Slurp` may be easier to write (not really), but just using open, while and print yourself has the advantage that you need to keep only one line at a time in memory. This makes a huge difference if you're processing gigabytes of files.
- Do not take this personally, but I think you need to research more yourself, and work with the standard documentation before asking other people.
- As a general advice in situations like these, start with smaller examples. First tackle the problem of just opening a file and printing it's content on stdout. Then add your processing of input - any changes to the content, or omitting some lines, inserting new lines, whatever. Finally add the code to write the new lines into another file. With this step-by-step approach you're not looking at a pile of problems, but can solve one small problem one at a time.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks "cfi".. for your valuable solution.

Comment: But Sir one more thing I would like to know from you, is :           File :: Slurp is used for read_file() and write_file(). Then how can it get affected if I write a open file function?

Comment: Earlier to this perl program posted, I have tried it using array. But its not working. I have used array with regex... But I faced alot of problems and is not getting solved.

Comment: Anyway again I thank you for your valuable response. Thanks "cfi".. :)

Comment: Sir you have given me the solution for lines, But how can i get the same result reading and writing character wise. Why I am emphasizing on character wise reading and writing in file is : I have the requirement like that. :)

Comment: All your requirements should be stated in the question. Otherwise people will waste time providing advice or solutions that don't work for you.

Comment: @Amit: You say "the requirement is like that" but do not give a reason. Without reason others cannot understand the requirement and cannot effectively spend their time to solve your problem the way you'd like it to be solved. Please be more open about what you want to achieve and why and how.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use File::Slurp;
use File::Slurp qw( :all );

open (In_FILE, 'matter.txt') || die("Could not open file!");
my $F1 = read_file('matter.txt');
$F1=ucfirst($F1);
print "$F1\n";
my $F2 =~ s/([\.\?!]\s*[a-z])/uc(&1)/ge;
my $F3 = write_file('copy_matter.txt', $F1);
write_file('copy_matter_1.txt', $F2);
close(In_FILE) || die("Could not close file!!");                                                                    QUESTION IS : WHY DOES "$F2" Doesnt work ?!!!

Comment: @Amit, your comment is not related directly to my answer and to your question. Pls also check perl documentation, other questions here related to regexp matching with =~ and/or try some printf() debugging or the real perl debugger to see why it's not working. In this particular case your regexp operates on $F2 which is uninitialized. You are reading the file into F1, then operate on data in F2. There's something missing inbetween. But please do not use comments as a long-term discussion forum

Comment: @Amit, in addition to showing that you did your own research, you could also use "upvoting" and/or "accepting an answer" (if e.g. M42 or I fully answered your question) to provide some motivation why people should help you in the future.